# EF Core 2.1.1 Seed data not working with override double

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, seeding

could you tell me why in my DB i get `0` values on after `Seed method`? This is how it looks like:

```
public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        int countOfWorkers = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < countOfWorkers; i++)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Driver>().HasData(
            new Driver
            {
                // 10 same workers
                Id = i + 1,
                FarmId = 1,
                FirstName = "name" + i,
                LastName = "lastname" + i,
                UsdPerHour = 7.2,
                HoursPerDay = 8,
                DaysOfWork = 31
            });
        }
    }
```

And my `Models` classes:

```
public abstract class Worker
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Farm")]
    public int FarmId { get; set; }
    public Farm Farm { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual double UsdPerHour { get; set; }
    public virtual int HoursPerDay { get; set; }
    public virtual int DaysOfWork { get; set; }

    public virtual double CountBaseSalary() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class Driver : Worker
{
    public Driver() => BaseSalary = CountBaseSalary();

    public override double UsdPerHour { get; set; }
    public override int HoursPerDay { get; set; }
    public override int DaysOfWork { get; set; }

    public override double CountBaseSalary() => UsdPerHour* HoursPerDay *DaysOfWork;

}
```

Im using `EF Core 2.1.1`. What i did wrong, that i get `0's` values for propertys on Driver? If needed, i can add more info.

My `DbContext`:

```
public class FarmDbContext : DbContext
{
    public FarmDbContext(DbContextOptions<FarmDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Farm> Farms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Worker> Workers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Driver>();
        builder.Seed();
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all `Worker` will have `UsdPerHour, HoursPerDay, DaysOfWork` then you do not need those fields specified in `Driver`, they will be inherited.

If only `Driver` needs those fields, then they should be removed from the base class `Worker`.